# How do I prevent the user from moving image (they can move the image with the arrow or WASD keys) off of the canvas?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, move

My program involves the user moving an image resembling the 'player character' using the arrow keys or the WASD keys. Is there code that can stop the user from moving the image off of the canvas?

Comment: It's just math. Compute what the coordinates would be after the move, and don't allow the move if they are off the screen.

Comment: Check if the sprite's boundary is outside of the canvas and if it is move it back. To get the boundary if the sprite use `<tkinter.Canvas>.bbox(<sprite id>)` which return a tuple of 4 coordinates `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`. The first 2 are the coordinates of the top left corner of the sprite and the last 2 are the coordinates of the bottom right corner of the sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would go about solving this with the information you provided:

```
if move.ending_x_coord < right_limit or move.ending_x_coord > left_limit or   
move.ending_y_coord < bottom_limit or move.ending_y_coord > top limit:
    move.is_valid = False
```